# Using CMD, Error with return value 3221225477, but using compiler online the program it's working

Tags: c++, c++11

i am writing this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int getOption();
void seeMenuKemeja();

int main(){
enter code int userOption = getOption();
int banyakPesanan;
char isContinue;

string kategoriMenu[100];
string keteranganBarang[100];
string kodeBarang[100];
string warnaPemesanan[banyakPesanan];
string kategoriPemesanan[banyakPesanan];

string ukuranPemesanan[banyakPesanan];


int userSelectStuff[banyakPesanan];
int jumlahPesanan[banyakPesanan];
int hargaSatuan[banyakPesanan];

enum option{KEMEJA = 1, TSHIRT, HOODIE, SHOES, ABOUT, END};

while(userOption != END){
    switch(userOption){
        case KEMEJA:{

            cout << endl;
            seeMenuKemeja();

            cout << "Banyak Jenis Kemeja yang ingin dipesan : ";
            cin >> banyakPesanan;
            cout << endl;

                if(banyakPesanan <= 0){
                    cout << "Can't be null" << endl;
                    goto labelContinue;
                }else{
                    for(int i = 1; i <= banyakPesanan; i++){
                        cout << "\t\t\t\t Jenis Ke - " << i << endl << endl;

                        cout << "Kode Kemeja yang dipesan : ";
                        cin >> userSelectStuff[i];
                        cout << "Pilih Warna Kemeja [ Merah(M), Hitam(H), Putih(P), Biru(B), Kuning(K), Navy(N) ] : ";
                        cin >> warnaPemesanan[i];
                        cout << "Pilih Ukuran Kemeja [ S = 1, M = 2, L = 3. XL = 4, XXL = 5 ] : ";
                        cin >> ukuranPemesanan[i];
                        cout << "Banya Kemeja yang dipesan : ";
                        cin >> jumlahPesanan[i];    
                        cout << endl;

                        if(userSelectStuff[i] == 1001){
                            kategoriMenu[i] = "Kemeja";
                            keteranganBarang[i] = "Kemeja Lengan Panjang";
                            kodeBarang[i] = "1001";
                            hargaSatuan[i] = 230000;

                            if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "M" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "m"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Merah";
                            }else if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "H" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "h"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Hitam";
                            }else if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "P" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "p"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Putih";
                            }else if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "B" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "b"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Biru";
                            }else if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "K" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "k"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Kuning";
                            }else if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "N" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "n"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Navy";
                            }else{
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Null";
                                hargaSatuan[i] = 0;
                            }

                            if(ukuranPemesanan[i] == "S" || ukuranPemesanan[i] == "1"){
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "S";
                            }else if(ukuranPemesanan[i] == "M" || ukuranPemesanan[i] == "2"){
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "M";
                            }else if(ukuranPemesanan[i] == "L" || ukuranPemesanan[i] == "3"){
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "L";
                            }else if(ukuranPemesanan[i] == "XL" || ukuranPemesanan[i] == "4"){
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "XL";
                            }else if(ukuranPemesanan[i] == "XXL" || ukuranPemesanan[i] == "5"){
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "XXL";
                            }else{
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "Null";
                                hargaSatuan[i] = 0;
                            }

                        } else if(userSelectStuff[i] == 1002){
                            kategoriMenu[i] = "Kemeja";
                            keteranganBarang[i] = "Kemeja Lengan Panjang";
                            kodeBarang[i] = "1001";
                            hargaSatuan[i] = 230000;

                            if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "M" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "m"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Merah";
                            }else if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "H" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "h"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Hitam";
                            }else if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "P" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "p"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Putih";
                            }else if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "B" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "b"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Biru";
                            }else if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "K" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "k"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Kuning";
                            }else if(warnaPemesanan[i] == "N" || warnaPemesanan[i] == "n"){
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Navy";
                            }else{
                                warnaPemesanan[i] = "Null";
                                hargaSatuan[i] = 0;
                            }

                            if(ukuranPemesanan[i] == "S" || ukuranPemesanan[i] == "1"){
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "S";
                            }else if(ukuranPemesanan[i] == "M" || ukuranPemesanan[i] == "2"){
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "M";
                            }else if(ukuranPemesanan[i] == "L" || ukuranPemesanan[i] == "3"){
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "L";
                            }else if(ukuranPemesanan[i] == "XL" || ukuranPemesanan[i] == "4"){
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "XL";
                            }else if(ukuranPemesanan[i] == "XXL" || ukuranPemesanan[i] == "5"){
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "XXL";
                            }else{
                                ukuranPemesanan[i] = "Null";
                                hargaSatuan[i] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                for(int i = 1; i <= banyakPesanan; i++){
                    cout << i << ends << kategoriMenu[i] << ends << keteranganBarang[i] << ends << userSelectStuff[i] << ends << warnaPemesanan[i] << ends;
                    cout << ukuranPemesanan[i] << ends << jumlahPesanan[i] << ends << hargaSatuan[i] << endl;
                }

            break;
        }
        case TSHIRT:{
            cout << "TShirt" << endl;
            break;
        }
        case HOODIE:{
            cout << "Hoodie" << endl;
            break;
        }
        case SHOES:{
            cout << "Shoes" << endl;
            break;
        }
        case ABOUT:{
            cout << "About" << endl;
            break;
        }
        default:{
            cout << "Choose About [1-6]" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    // 
    labelContinue:

    cout << "Lanjutkan [ Y / N ] : ";
    cin >> isContinue;
        if( (isContinue == 'y') | (isContinue == 'Y') ){
            userOption = getOption();
        }else if ( (isContinue == 'n') | (isContinue == 'N') ){
            break;
        }else{
            goto labelContinue;
        }
}


cout << "End of Program.." << endl;


cin.get();
return 0;


}

int getOption(){
int input;

system("cls");

cout << "\t\tWelcome " << endl;
cout << "\t     Fashion Store " << endl;
cout << " ============================================= " << endl;
cout << " 1. \t Kemeja " << endl;
cout << " 2. \t T-Shirt" << endl;
cout << " 3. \t Hoodie" << endl;
cout << " 4. \t Shoes" << endl;
cout << " 5. \t About Program " << endl;
cout << " 6. \t End Program " << endl;
cout << " =============================================" << endl;

cout << "Choose your option [1-6].... ";

cin >> input;
return input;
}

void seeMenuKemeja(){
char menuKemeja[5][3][25] = {{"1", "2", "3"},
                              {"Kemeja Lengan Panjang", "Kemeja Lengan Pendek", "Kemeja Flanel"},
                              {"1001", "1002", "1003"},
                              {"S, M, L, XL, XXL", "S, M, L, XL, XXL", "S, M, L, XL, XXL", },
                              {"Rp. 230.000,-", "Rp. 180.000,-", "Rp. 150.000,-"}
                             };


                cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\tKemeja" << endl;
                cout << "=====================================================================================================================" << endl;
                cout << "No.\t  Jenis                         Kode                       Ukuran         Harga" << endl;
                cout << "=====================================================================================================================" << endl;
                cout << menuKemeja[0][0] << ends << "\t" << menuKemeja[1][0] << ends << "\t\t" << menuKemeja[2][0] << ends << "\t\t\t" << menuKemeja[3][0] << "\t" << menuKemeja[4][0] << endl;
                cout << menuKemeja[0][1] << ends << "\t" << menuKemeja[1][1] << ends << "\t\t" << menuKemeja[2][1] << ends << "\t\t\t" << menuKemeja[3][1] << "\t" << menuKemeja[4][1] << endl;
                cout << menuKemeja[0][2] << ends << "\t" << menuKemeja[1][2] << ends << "\t\t\t" << menuKemeja[2][2] << ends << "\t\t\t" << menuKemeja[3][2] << "\t" << menuKemeja[4][2] << endl;
                cout << "=====================================================================================================================" << endl;
                cout << endl;
     }
```

My code is compiling successfully but immediately after that I'm getting the message "Process exited with return value 3221225725".
The code is working fine in cpp.sh
What should I do? ( Btw, I using Dev C++ 5.11 )

For Example :
 1. I input cin >> banyakPesanan; ( Ex: 5, it's fine ), 
 and i input cin >> userSelectStuff[i] ( Ex: 1001, it's fine ), 
 and next step when i input on cin >> warnaPemesanan[i] ( Ex : N ),

my CMD error, Process exited with return value 3221225477, and if i'm using compiler online cpp.sh, the program will be working fine.

Please help me, thank you !

Comment: `string warnaPemesanan[banyakPesanan]` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `banyakPesanan`

Comment: When you see a strange return code like 3221225725 turn it into hex (C00000FD) and see if that is more recognizable. Even if you don't know what it means it's likely your choice of web search engines will.